# How to set application name at runtime

Tags: javafx

Whether I run my JavaFX application in the IDE or build and run the .jar, the application's name showing in the toolbar is basically the Main class :

[image: app name in toolbar]

I tried to build the artifact with IntelliJ and also with Maven (`$ mvn clean package`), but same result for both. I'm using JDK8 on Ubuntu.

Is there a way to change the application name/title?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no programmatic way to set the application name in JavaFX. This can however be done when you package your application via the new jpackage tool (JDK 14).